# Order by properly on SNMP oids

Tags: php, mysql, python-3.x, datatables, sqlalchemy

I've searched and tried lots of things but I can't find a solution.

I am storing some SNMP OIDs in a database, and displaying them in a table with datatables.

I want the OIDs to be displayed in the correct order so for example:

```
1.3.6.1.2.1.1
1.3.6.1.2.1.10
1.3.6.1.2.1.2
```

In correct order would be:

```
1.3.6.1.2.1.1
1.3.6.1.2.1.2
1.3.6.1.2.1.10
```

A SQL query with order by on the column storing the OID string would order them:

```
1.3.6.1.2.1.1
1.3.6.1.2.1.10
1.3.6.1.2.1.2
```

I'm using serverside processing with either PHP or preferably python flask. Currently I am building the table myself in flask and have written a function that orders them by converting the OIDs to tuples and sorting. This works but I would like to use datatables to get the pagination and responsiveness.

One thing to note is there isn't a limit on the length of the OID.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a hack, but it might work. If each element in the OID has a max value < 100, then create a second column in the database, where each element is converted to a 2-digit 0-filled value:

```
real_oid           sorting_oid
1.3.6.1.2.1.1      01.03.06.01.02.01.01
1.3.6.1.2.1.10     01.03.06.01.02.01.10
1.3.6.1.2.1.2      01.03.06.01.02.01.02
```

You could even eliminate the periods to save space, once you tested that is is all working.

Answer (score 0):

First split the string on the period and typecast to int. Then use `sorted` and `operator.itemgetter` to sort by multiple attributes. Then re-join using a period. Something like the following:

```
original_oids = [...]
split_and_typecast_oids = [map(int, oid.split(".")) for oid in original_oids]
sorted_oids = sorted(split_and_typecast_oids, operator.itemgetter(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))
rejoined_oids = [".".join(map(str, oid)) for oid in sorted_oids]
```